# How can I dynamically create derived classes from a base class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

For example I have a base class as follows:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, classtype):
        self._type = classtype
```

From this class I derive several other classes, e.g.

```
class TestClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__('Test')

class SpecialClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__('Special')
```

Is there a nice, pythonic way to create those classes dynamically by a function call that puts the new class into my current scope, like:

```
foo(BaseClass, "My")
a = MyClass()
...
```

As there will be comments and questions why I need this: The derived classes all have the exact same internal structure with the difference, that the constructor takes a number of previously undefined arguments. So, for example, `MyClass` takes the keywords `a` while the constructor of class `TestClass` takes `b` and `c`.

```
inst1 = MyClass(a=4)
inst2 = MyClass(a=5)
inst3 = TestClass(b=False, c = "test")
```

But they should NEVER use the type of the class as input argument like

```
inst1 = BaseClass(classtype = "My", a=4)
```

I got this to work but would prefer the other way, i.e. dynamically created class objects.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want the type of instance to change depending on the supplied arguments? Like if I give an `a` it will always be `MyClass` and `TestClass` will never take an `a`? Why not just declare all 3 arguments in `BaseClass.__init__()` but default them all to `None`? `def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, C=None)`?

Comment: I cannot declare anything in the base class, as i do not know all arguments I might use. I might have 30 different clases with 5 different arguments each, so declaring 150 arguments in the constructur is not a solution.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

This bit of code allows you to create new classes with dynamic 
names and parameter names. 
The parameter verification  in `__init__` just does not allow
unknown parameters, if you need other verifications, like
type, or that they are mandatory, just add the logic
there:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, classtype):
        self._type = classtype

def ClassFactory(name, argnames, BaseClass=BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            # here, the argnames variable is the one passed to the
            # ClassFactory call
            if key not in argnames:
                raise TypeError("Argument %s not valid for %s" 
                    % (key, self.__class__.__name__))
            setattr(self, key, value)
        BaseClass.__init__(self, name[:-len("Class")])
    newclass = type(name, (BaseClass,),{"__init__": __init__})
    return newclass
```

And this works like this, for example:

```
>>> SpecialClass = ClassFactory("SpecialClass", "a b c".split())
>>> s = SpecialClass(a=2)
>>> s.a
2
>>> s2 = SpecialClass(d=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __init__
TypeError: Argument d not valid for SpecialClass
```

I see you are asking for inserting the dynamic names in the naming scope --
now, *that* is not considered a good practice in Python - you either have
variable names, known at coding time, or data - and names learned in runtime
are more "data" than "variables" -

So, you could just add your classes to a dictionary and use them from there:

```
name = "SpecialClass"
classes = {}
classes[name] = ClassFactory(name, params)
instance = classes[name](...)
```

And if your design absolutely needs the names to come in scope,
just do the same, but use the dictionary returned by the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) 
call instead of an arbitrary dictionary:

```
name = "SpecialClass"
globals()[name] = ClassFactory(name, params)
instance = SpecialClass(...)
```

(It indeed would be possible for the class factory function to insert the name dynamically on the global scope of the caller - but that is even worse practice, and is not compatible across Python implementations. The way to do that would be to get the caller's execution frame, through [sys._getframe(1)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) and setting the class name in the frame's global dictionary in its `f_globals` attribute).

**update, tl;dr:** This answer had become popular, still its very specific to the question body. The general answer on how to 
*"dynamically create derived classes from a base class"*
 in Python is a simple call to `type` passing the new class name, a tuple with the baseclass(es) and the `__dict__` body for the new class -like this:

```
>>> new_class = type("NewClassName", (BaseClass,), {"new_method": lambda self: ...})
```

**update**
Anyone needing this should also check the [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) project - it claims to be able to pickle and unpickle classes just like pickle does to ordinary objects, and had lived to it in some of my tests.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `BaseClass.__init__()` would be better as the more general `super(self.__class__).__init__()`, which plays more nicely when the new classes are subclassed. (Reference: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: @EOL: It would for statically declared classes - but since you don't have the actual class name to hardcode as the first parameter to Super, that would require a lot of dancing around. Try replacing it with `super` above and create a subclass of a dynamically created class to understand it; And, on the other hand, in this case you can have the baseclass as a general objectfrom which to call  `__init__`.

Comment: Now I had some time to look at the suggested solution, but it is not quite what I want. First, it looks like `__init__` of `BaseClass` is called with one argument, but in fact `BaseClass.__init__` always takes an arbitrary list of keyword arguments. Second, the solution above sets all the allowed parameter names as attributes, which is not what I want. ANY argument HAS to go to `BaseClass`, but which one I know when creating the derived class. I probably will update the question or ask a more precise one to make it clearer.

Comment: @jsbueno: Right, using the `super()` I was mentioning gives `TypeError: must be type, not SubSubClass`. If I understand correctly, this comes from the first argument `self` of `__init__()`, which is a `SubSubClass` where a `type` object is expected: this seems related to the fact `super(self.__class__)` is a unbound super object. What is its `__init__()` method? I'm not sure which such method could require a first argument of type `type`. Could you explain? (Side note: my `super()` approach indeed does not make sense, here, because `__init__()` has a variable signature.)

Comment: @EOL: the major problem is actually if you create another subclass of the factorized class: self.__class__ will refer to that subclass, not the class in which "super" is called - and you get infinite recursion.

Comment: @Alex: both the argument setting and calling `__init__` of the baseclasswith just one parameter are just two ordinary lines, and not part of the "solution" of creating the classes dynamically - At this point, it is not quite clear for me what you are needing - but you certainy can change these behaviors in the code above.

Comment: In dynamic paradigam this does not best fit

Answer (score 120):

[`type()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) is the function that creates classes and in particular sub-classes, like in the question:

```
def set_x(self, value):
    self.x = value

# type() takes as argument the new class name, its base
# classes, and its attributes:
SubClass = type('SubClass', (BaseClass,), {'set_x': set_x})
# (More methods can be put in SubClass, including __init__().)

obj = SubClass()
obj.set_x(42)
print obj.x  # Prints 42
print isinstance(obj, BaseClass)  # True
```

Comment: In trying to understand this example using Python 2.7, I got a `TypeError` that said `__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.  I found that adding something (anything?) to fill the gap would suffice.  For example, `obj = SubClass('foo')` runs without error.

Comment: This is normal, since `SubClass` is a sub-class of `BaseClass` in the question and `BaseClass` takes a parameter (`classtype`, which is `'foo'` in your example).

Comment: @EricOLebigot Can I make a call to init of BaseClass here somehow? like with super?

Comment: Yes, and still with `super()`, but the Python interpreter cannot work its magic anymore and interpret a bare `super()` directly, so you must use in `set_x` (or any other method of `SubClass`) the more explicit form `super(SubClass, self).__init__()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case :

```py
inst3 = globals()["SpecialClass"](b=False, c = "test")
```

Answer (score -5):

To create a class with a dynamic attribute value, checkout the code below.
NB. This are code snippets in python programming language

```
def create_class(attribute_data, **more_data): # define a function with required attributes
    class ClassCreated(optional extensions): # define class with optional inheritance
          attribute1 = adattribute_data # set class attributes with function parameter
          attribute2 = more_data.get("attribute2")

    return ClassCreated # return the created class

# use class

myclass1 = create_class("hello") # *generates a class*
```