# Python3: Changing inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I thought that I wanted to change the inheritence of a class but then I read this [How to dynamically change base class of instances at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/how-to-dynamically-change-base-class-of-instances-at-runtime) which says that this is a bad idea. I have learnt the hard way that when lots of people on SO say don't do this but you do it anyway then you eventually regret it. However, I'm struggling to see how I can avoid it. So I would like to present my problem and see if anyone has any opinions on how one might overcome this problem.

I have two libraries `Frame` and `Imp`.

**Frame**:

`Frame` is a collection of classes that act as a kind of framework for developing tools.

There are five classes in this library.

`Frame.A(metaclass=ABCMeta)`:

Is an abstract class that everything will inherit from.

The next level forks into two types of objects:
`Frame.B(A)` and `Frame.C(A)`.

`Frame.C` does not have any more children but `Frame.B` does and forks again:
`Frame.D(B)` and `Frame.E(B)`.

**IMP:**
We decide that we want to use the `Frame` framework to create a specific tool and create two classes 
`Imp.A(Frame.D)` and `Imp.B(Frame.E)` objects. However it turns out that we create lots of methods that are the same in both `Imp.A` and `Imp.B`.

Since we don't want lots of repeated code we look at adding a class that has the communal methods and so `Imp.A` and `Imp.B` can both inherit from. The problem is that these functions are much too specifc to go in the `Frame` library and it doesn't make sense to not have `Frame.D` and `Frame.E` in the `Imp` library.

One could create an exact replica of `Frame.D` (`Imp.FD`) and `Frame.E` (`Imp.FE`) in `Imp` plus the new base class (`Imp.New`) so we have the following structure:

`Imp.New(Frame.B)`

`Imp.FD(Imp.New)`

`Imp.FE(Imp.New)`

`Imp.A(Imp.FD)`

`Imp.B(Imp.FE)`

However we now have two (almost identical) copies of two classes (`Imp.FD` = `Frame.D` and `Imp.FE` = `Frame.E`) which makes development etc a bit of a pain.

If I could just create `Imp.New(Frame.B)` and use `Frame.D` and `Frame.E` but simply modified to inherit from `Imp.New` instead of `Frame.B` then that would be perfect. However, aparently this is bad practice: [How to dynamically change base class of instances at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/how-to-dynamically-change-base-class-of-instances-at-runtime)

Can anyone suggest a solution to my problem?

**Addition:**
The accepted answer at [Pass a parent class as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683097/pass-a-parent-class-as-an-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows a way of defining a class inside a function so that one can choose the parent class. I could use this technique so that `Frame.D` and `Frame.E` both have variable parent classes but it feels a little hacky and won't it muck up the help function/docstrings when people use it?

This doesn't seem like a particularly unusual situation, surely there must be some protocal for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) or [using mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)

This is probably a case for composition, but I included mixins just in case.

Here is an example using imagined `Frame` and `Imp` classes.

```
class Frame(object):
    def do_thing(self, stuff):
        raise NotImplementedError


class A(Frame):
    def __init__(self, thingy):
        self.thingy = thingy

    def do_thing(self, stuff):
        return stuff + self.thingy


class B(Frame):
    def __init__(self, thingy):
        self.thingy = thingy

    def do_thing(self, stuff):
        return stuff - self.thingy


class CrazyB(B):
    def __init__(self, thingy):
        self.dingus = 5
        super(CrazyB, self).__init__(thingy)

    def go_crazy(self):
        return self.dingus + self.thingy - 10**10
```

#### COMPOSITION

```
class Imp(object):
    def __init__(self, frame, stuff):
        self.frame = frame
        self.stuff = stuff

    def be_impish(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def do_frame_stuff(self):
        return self.frame.do_thing(self.stuff)

# OR ALSO COMPOSITION

class ImpAlternate(object):
    frame_class = None

    def __init__(self, frame_arg, stuff):
        self.frame = self.frame_class(frame_arg)
        self.stuff = stuff

    def be_impish(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def do_frame_stuff(self):
        return self.frame.do_thing(self.stuff)


class ImpA(ImpAlternate):
    frame_class = CrazyB

    def be_impish(self):
        return self.frame.go_crazy()
```

#### MIXINS

```
class ThingyShower(object):
    def show_thingy(self):
        try:
            thingy =  str(getattr(self, 'thingy'))
        except AttributeError:
            thingy =  'no thingy'
        return 'thingy: {}'.format(thingy)


class ImpB(B, ThingyShower):
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        super(ImpB, self).__init__(stuff)
```

in action:

```
>>> x = ImpA(11, 22)
>>> print(x.be_impish())
-9999999984
>>> print(x.do_frame_stuff())
11

>>> y = ImpB(25)
>>> print(y.do_thing(10))
-15
>>> print(y.show_thingy())
thingy: 25
```