# Inheriting from classes unpacked from a list

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Say I have a list of class objects in Python (`A, B, C`) and I want to inherit from all of them when building class `D`, such as:

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(object):
    pass

class C(object):
    pass


classes = [A, B, C]

class D(*classes):
    pass
```

Unfortunately I get a syntax error when I do this. How else can I accomplish it, other than by writing `class D(A, B, C)`? (There are more than three classes in my actual scenario)

Comment: [In Python 3, you'll be able to just do that.](http://ideone.com/fXvAHL)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dynamically create classes using [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) keyword, as in:

```
>>> classes = [A, B, C]
>>> D = type('D', tuple(classes), {})
>>> type(D)
<class 'type'>
>>> D.__bases__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>)
```

see [15247075](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247075/how-can-i-dynamically-create-derived-classes-from-a-base-class) for more examples.

Comment: Pure awesomeness to a literally impossible situation. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

One way will be to create a decorator that then creates a new class for us using `type()`:

```
def modify_bases(bases):
    def decorator(cls):
        return type(cls.__name__, tuple(classes), dict(cls.__dict__))
    return decorator
...
>>> %cpaste
@modify_bases(classes)
class D:
    x = 1
    y = 2

>>> D.mro()
[<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <type 'object'>]
```

Comment: Pure awesomeness to decorate a literally impossible situation. +1 :D