# Python C/API: how to create a normal class

Tags: python, class, python-c-api

Using the Python C/API, how do I create a normal Python class using the normal Python class-creation mechanism (i.e.: not an extension type)?

In other words, what is the Python C/API equivalent (in the sense that it does *exactly* the same in all cases) of a statement

```
class X(bases):
    ...some methods/attributes here...
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the normal Python class-creation mechanism", but...

There's a documentation page dedicated to this: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html -- it creates a new type in an extension module, which is equivalent to creating a new `class` in Python code.

The minimal example presented there is:

```
#include <Python.h>

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    /* Type-specific fields go here. */
} noddy_NoddyObject;

static PyTypeObject noddy_NoddyType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "noddy.Noddy",             /* tp_name */
    sizeof(noddy_NoddyObject), /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
    0,                         /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                         /* tp_print */
    0,                         /* tp_getattr */
    0,                         /* tp_setattr */
    0,                         /* tp_reserved */
    0,                         /* tp_repr */
    0,                         /* tp_as_number */
    0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                         /* tp_hash  */
    0,                         /* tp_call */
    0,                         /* tp_str */
    0,                         /* tp_getattro */
    0,                         /* tp_setattro */
    0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,        /* tp_flags */
    "Noddy objects",           /* tp_doc */
};

static PyModuleDef noddymodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "noddy",
    "Example module that creates an extension type.",
    -1,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_noddy(void)
{
    PyObject* m;

    noddy_NoddyType.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
    if (PyType_Ready(&noddy_NoddyType) < 0)
        return NULL;

    m = PyModule_Create(&noddymodule);
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Py_INCREF(&noddy_NoddyType);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "Noddy", (PyObject *)&noddy_NoddyType);
    return m;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do NOT want. I do not want an extension type, but just a Python class created at runtime.

Comment: @JeroenDemeyer: Your questions says "Python C/API equivalent of a statement like", so this is what I understood. Please consider rephrasing your question to be clearer.

Comment: I mean "equivalent" in the most literal sense. I don't mean "similar", I really mean "exactly the same".

Answer (score 4):

In Python you can get programmatically create a class by calling the `type` built in function. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15247202/4657412) for example.

This takes three arguments: a name, a tuple of bases, and a dictionary.

You can get the Python `type` in the C api as [`PyType_Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/type.html#c.PyType_Type). You then just need to call it using [one of the standard methods for calling `PyObject*` callables](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Call):

```c
// make a tuple of your bases
PyObject* bases = PyTuple_Pack(0); // assume no bases
// make a dictionary of member functions, etc
PyObject* dict = PyDict_New(); // empty for the sake of example 
PyObject* my_new_class = PyObject_CallFunction(&PyType_Type,"sOO",
                                             "X", // class name
                                             bases,
                                             dict);
// check if null

// decref bases and dict
Py_CLEAR(bases);
Py_CLEAR(dict);
```

(Note that you have to do `&PyType_Type` - the documentation implies that it's a `PyObject*` but it isn't!)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Although I wonder if "class Derived(Base): pass" is really 100% equivalent to "Derived = type("Derived", (Base,), {})" if metaclasses are involved.

Comment: I believe that if metaclasses are involved you should call `Derived = metaclass("Derived", (Base,), {})`. However, this is slightly beyond what I'm actually sure of...

Comment: Just as an extra thing - have you seen this https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-July/090921.html? There does look to be a second way of doing it involving allocating `PyTypeObject`s yourself (but no-one seems to like it...)