# How to dynamically create classes in __init__.py

Tags: python

Is it possible to dynamically create classes in the `__init__.py` file.

I'll give an example. Let's say I have this hierarchy:

```
script.py
module\
 --> __init__.py
```

In the python file `script.py`, I want to know if I can, with this call:

`from module import my_class`

dynamically create the `my_class` definition in the `__init__.py`

Comment: Even if you *can*, doesn't mean you *should*....

Comment: Also, there's no real significance to `__init__.py` here.

Comment: look into type class creation. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15247892 for example, and more specifically, this line: `newclass = type(name, (BaseClass,),{"__init__": __init__})`.  do you however have **good** reason to create a class on the fly?  It's a little bit like a metaclass question:  more often than not, if you gotta ask, you don't need it.