# Defining Classes using a Function

Tags: python, class

Using Python, I would like to define multiple classes using a function. For example, I want to code something along the lines of:

```
def addClass(className, x, y):
    #Creates new class called className which contains definitions for x and y.

addClass("position", 100, 200)

#Expected Resulting Class:
#
#class position:
#    x = 100
#    y = 200

print(position.x)

#Expected Output:
#
#100
```

After defining multiple classes with this function, I'd like to be able to access the `x` and `y` values of all of those classes in the form `className.x` or `className.y`. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Or if it is even possible? Or if there is a better way to accomplish the same task?

Comment: This is simply not a good idea.  It doesn't save any typing; by using dataclasses, and it doesn't add any clarity.  You can define your class with the same number of keystrokes.

Comment: Look at class factories, e.g. [this description](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-factories-a-powerful-pattern-in-python/)

Comment: @TimRoberts No offense but...I don't think it should matter if what they are trying to do is a good idea or not. They just have something they wanna try, so just let them do that. With time, they'll learn the difference between good ideas and bad ideas.

Comment: There is most likely a solution not involving external libraries, but you can also do this with Pydantic's `create_model`: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I dynamically create derived classes from a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247075/how-can-i-dynamically-create-derived-classes-from-a-base-class)

Comment: @IshanShishodiya -- I disagree completely.  If someone is trying to pound in a nail with a banana, is it better to tell them how to do it, or to tell them to use a hammer?  The PROBLEM they have has a simpler solution.  That's what we need to provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing this,

```
def addClass(className, x, y):
  return type(className, (object,), {"x": x, "y": "y"})

position = addClass("position", 100, 200)
print(position.x)
```

Output -

```
100
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what is the reason for you to do this (there aren't too many), but here is one way:

```
def addClass(className, x, y):
    globals()[className] = type(className, (), dict(x=x, y=y))

addClass("position", 100, 200)

print(position.x)
```

Comment: This only affects the global scope and doesn't return the class.

Comment: Just like in the example from topic starter, right?