# Python create dynamic class and set multi bases from imported module

Tags: python-3.x, class

I found several example here, but is not what exactly looking for, will try to explain here
from this answer tried to achieve my result but is not what looking for
[How can I dynamically create derived classes from a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247075/how-can-i-dynamically-create-derived-classes-from-a-base-class)

**i have a module that holds many classes**

importing the module

```
import importlib

# are awalable many classes here
forms = importlib.import_module('my_forms')
```

Now, based on **forms** i need to create a new class and add bases to my new class all classes that are availabe in **forms**

this what i tried, but can not find a way to assign the bases

import inspect

```
def create_DynamicClass():
    class DynamicClass(BaseClass):
        pass

    for form_name, class_name in inspect.getmembers(forms):
        for i in class_name():
            # here the code to added all bases to DynamicClass
            
    return DynamicClass()
```

example how my_forms module looks

```
class MyClass1(BaseClass):
    
    attr1 = 1
    attr2 = 2
    
    @coroutine
    def prepare(self):
        # some code for each class

class MyClass2(BaseClass):
    
    attr3 = 3
    attr4 = 4
    
    @coroutine
    def prepare(self):
        # some code for each class

class MyClass3(BaseClass):
    
    attr5 = 5
    attr6 = 6
    
    @coroutine
    def prepare(self):
        # some code for each class
```

The result that i want to achieve is the following, will make a static class to show desired result but need to be dynamic

I need to create my class dynamic because in my_forms module can be any amount of classes

```
# inherits all classes from my_forms module
class MyResultClass(MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3):

    # here get all available attributes from all classes
    

    @coroutine
    def prepare(self):
        # as well need each prepare function for each class as well
        yield MyClass1().prepare()
        yield MyClass2().prepare()
        yield MyClass3().prepare()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have managed to find a solution, will post here, if any recommendation to make it better will appreciate

```
forms = importlib.import_module('my_forms')

class Form(BaseForm):

    @coroutine
    def prepare(self):
        for form_name, class_name in inspect.getmembers(forms, inspect.isclass):
            try:
                yield class_name().prepare()
            except TypeError:
                continue


def createClass(meta):
    for form_name, class_name in inspect.getmembers(forms, inspect.isclass):
        try:
            Form.__bases__ += (class_name, )
            for field in class_name():
                field_type = fl.SelectField() if hasattr(field, 'choices') else fl.StringField()
                setattr(Form, field.name, field_type)
        except TypeError:
            continue
    return Form(meta=meta)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare the dynamic class with all of your base classes. To do so, put all of your base classes in a list, and unpack the list in the class definition statement with the `*` operator like this:

```
def createClass(baseClasess):
    class NewClass(*baseClasses):
       pass
    
    return NewClass

DynamicClass = createClass([class1, class2, ...])
```

Comment: And as an aside, make sure you really need to do this. If you simply want a single object with dynamic functionality which is defined in the base classes, delegation might be a better way than creating a new class with multi-inheritance.

Comment: thanks for answer, i have managed to find a solution, will post below maybe is not the best but any recommendation to make better will appreciate

Comment: yes i need to with multi inheritance, because what i try to do, to get all class attributes and all attributes choices for wtforms, as this forms have them declared in a module but this dynamic class in different module